# Django tutorial customize admin template

Tags: python, django

I'm working through the official Django tutorial. At the end of [part two](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/) they have you customize the admin template just a bit (changing some heading text). I think I've done everything right, but apparently I haven't because the admin site looks exactly the same after running syncdb and restarting the server. My project directory (excluding the virtualenv part) looks like this:

```
mysite
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── polls
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── templates
    └── admin
        └── base_site.html
```

In settings.py I have these lines added to make the project use the template in templates/admin:

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

later:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),)
```

I've tried several combinations of slashes and variations on assigning the value to `PROJECT_PATH` and `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, but haven't gotten anything to work. Each time I verified that it was actually making a filepath string (with a simple print statement).

To try to see what was going on I edited the original Django base_site.html it its admin folder and that changed my site, so it's obviously still using that. I've read several SO posts, and I don't really know what to do anymore.

Oh, and if it's relevant: Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing I would try is deleting your *.pyc files they often contain stale information which sometimes can cause issues likes this.

If that isn't the case I would then double check your `PROJECT_PATH` which I believe is the issue here.

`dirname` gets you the containing directory. so if that line is in the settings.py it will return `/path/to/inner/mysite`  the one inside the main mysite and since there is not `templates` directory in your inner `mysite` it wont work.

what you need to do is this.

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Which will return you the outer `mysite` path when combined with templates it will return you the correct path.

Everything should then work.

Comment: You were exactly right about my PROJECT_PATH variable being wrong. Modified it to yours and it works perfectly. Thanks!